# How to mount a zip file as a file system?

Tags: mount, archive, zip

Can I mount a zip (or other non-solid (so that accessing a file wouldn't decompress the whole archive) compressed archive format file) as a file system in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 26):

Install the package `avfs` then execute:

```
mountavfs
```

Say you have a zip file in `~/Documents/file.zip`, then

```
cd ~/.avfs/home/$USER/Documents
ls -l file.zip#/
```

You could also browse the content in Nautilus, but you need to add a trailing `#` character by hand to the path (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to access the address bar).

Comment: Very cool!!  *At the moment it supports floppies, tar and gzip files, zip, bzip2, ar and rar files, ftp sessions, http, webdav, rsh/rcp, ssh/scp.
 Quite a few other handlers are implemented with the Midnight Commander's external FS*

Comment: Nice! I was searching for a tool that could mount a rar split into several files, like File.part1.rar, File.part2.rar, etc... or the alternate chunk.rar, chunk.r00 chunck.r01, etc... Apparently avfs is not capable of doing that. Any other solution?

Comment: Amazing! I had a virtual machine downloaded in zip that needed importing and this avoided me having to unzip dozens of gigs, all in less than 30 seconds. I love Linux :)

Answer (score 5):

In Nautilus, right click on the archive and then click "`Open with Archive Mounter`", once you've done this, your archive will show up as a new “drive” in Nautilus. ([check tutorial here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mount-archive-file-clicks-ubuntu/))

Comment: Intriguing - thanks.  But this doesn't actually mount the file like avfs does.  I.e. `/proc/mounts` doesn't change.  Archive Mounter uses gvfs, which I guess lets you use `gvfs-copy, gvfs-ls, gvfs-rm` etc, but I see no way to use most commands, e.g. md5sum.

Answer (score 1):

fuse-zip is a fuse filesystem, that enables any program to work with a ZIP archive as though it is a plain directory. Unlike KIO or Gnome VFS, it can be used in any application without modifications.

https://github.com/google/mount-zip