# How to go into a directory from an archive using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, archive

Like I use `cd` to go into a normal directory, how to `cd` into a directory from an archive (compressed file, such as .zip, .tar.gz, etc.) and see its content using the terminal? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if by "archive" you mean a compressed file (such as zip) then perhaps this answer will help?

[How to mount a zip file as a file system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94649/how-to-mount-a-zip-file-as-a-file-system)

After mounting the archive you would be able to `cd` into it.